# "Describes me to the 'T'" - why not the to the "E" or some other letter?

Tags: expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin of “Fits [x] to a T”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/origin-of-fits-x-to-a-t)

I was about to tell someone that the article they shared "described me to the 'T'" only to realize that, while I understand the message the expression is trying to convey, I have no idea where it came from or what it really means.

Someone, please describe :to the 'T'" the origin and meaning of describing something "to the 'T'".

Comment: I'm used to this being "described [pronoun/hame] to *a* T", not to *the* T.