# "To a T" or "To a Tee", and where does it come from?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, idioms, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin of “Fits [x] to a T”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/origin-of-fits-x-to-a-t)

I frequently hear the phrase "To a T[ee]", but I'm not sure that I've ever seen it written. What is the correct way to write this phrase, and what are its origins?

Comment: Not quite an _exact_ duplicate; the earlier question asks about the phrase's origin, but not about the variant spelling.  No matter; I've appended an answer there that addresses the variation issue (short answer: both _to a T_ and _to a tee_ are in use).